# How do I read a Django HTTPResponse in Flex?

Tags: django, apache-flex, flex3

I'm a complete Flex noob, so I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

I wrote a fairly simple file uploader in Flex, which calls my Django back-end via URLRequest (the FileReference object handles the upload).  My upload works as intended and I have Django return a HTTPResponse object.  As such, I'd like to read the contents of the HTTPResponse object.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something along the lines of

```
<mx:HTTPService id="myHTTPRequest" 
    url="{whatever your url request is}"
    result="resultHandler(event)" 
    fault="faultHandler(event)"
    showBusyCursor="true" 
    resultFormat="object">
```

then inside the resultHandler something like this

```
private function resultHandler (event : ResultEvent) : void {
    var obj : Object = event.result;
    //do something with returned object

}
```

Debug at the point of the resultHandler to see exaclty whats being returned, make sure its what you think should be getting returned.

Comment: I'd like to go this route, but FileReference.upload() expects a URLRequest as the first parameter.  I've tried using "as URLRequest", but no luck.  Any advice?

Comment: hmm thats quite a different thing then. I'm pretty sure that you can't get at the response.  If you use a HTTP service like above then fine, if your using the FileReference then all you can get is the events such as complete, progress, IO_error etc.

Comment: Could you on the complete event from the fileReference then create and send a HTTP request to get whatever your sending back? what data do you want back, the upload should just be a upload and not a upload and return data.

Answer (score 2):

By the time it gets to the client it's just a normal HTTP response so treat it like any other response

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to flex and I ran in the same problem when doing an upload to a Java Rest backend, I solved it using the DateEvent on the FileReference. To get the response data use something like this.:

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, responseHandler);
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourUrl");
fileRef.upload(request, "fileData"); 

private function responseHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
    var response:XML = new XML(event.data); 
//Note the DataEvent: this is the event that holds the response. 
//I sent back data as xml
}
```

Your response should always be a successful HTTP status code (200), if your backend sends status 500 codes it will not trigger the DateEvent. Server errors can still be caught with a HTTPStatusEvent, but then you don't have access to the response.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the response like so in your onComplete event handler:

```
private function saveCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    trace("saveCompleteHandler - event returned:" + loader.data as String);
}
```

we do this this to get json fron a java web service.

you just need to use a URLLoader to load the URLRequest in the first place:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, statusHandler, 10000);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, saveErrorHandler, 10000);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveCompleteHandler, 10000);

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http:/whereverer");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
loader.load(request);
```